# With JS or PHP, Update the URL in browsers address bar -without- going to it?

Tags: javascript, iphone, android

In making a mobi site act like an iPhone app (using jQuery, JS, PHP), we've run into a problem: the URL stays the same (www.example.com) I would like to append copy-paste friendly additions onto the end of the URL but i do not want the page to redirect or refresh (the links are totally valid, and land on a specific profile page, and we have a google indexable sitemap for that. We just dont want to sacrifice all the cool jQuery animation we implemented just to have copy-friendly URLs..)

For exmaple, lets say were on www.example.com 
When a person clicks on a profile link in the ListView like result, the url changes to
www.example.com/CategoryName/ListingName/ID
which, again, is totally valid on our site, but updating the URL always takes us directly to the page, sacrificing the slide animation emulating the look of loading from ListViews in iPhone.

Any ideas?

Comment: +1 For asking the question with example.com instead of an arbitrary domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

Make sure you build the system so the URI actually works if hit directly. [Progressive enhancement](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/) is a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the hash part of the URL for this:

www.example.com#some_state

Then parse it (`document.location.hash`) with JavaScript and change the content that is displayed based on that.

Changing any other part of a URL will cause a request to the backend to be made.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at HTML's new [history API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html)? Github is using this on the pages for browsing though project files.